# Upgrading to TLS1.2 (LINUX C++ GSOAP), encounter SSL_ERROR_SYSCAL

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux, tls1.2, gsoap

Q1: We would like to know the possible root cause of the following:
After upgrading  from gsoap 2.8.21 to 2.8.70 , we encountered issue upon executing SSL_Connect (during handshake) when we are trying to use one of the methods of the generated gsoap proxy classes . Below is the error we encountered:

Issue:
Error 30 fault detected [no subcode]
"SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL
Error observed by underlying SSL/TLS BIO: Connection reset by peer"
Detail: SSL_connect() error in tcp_connect()

Result of initial investigation:
Upon debugging we gathered some information about the problem:

1. The issue occur inside tcp_connect function when ssl_connect is being executed. It returned value -1., since it was inside a loop initial value of SSL_get_error is 2 then tcp_select is executed and value is  1
2. For the  second loop in the ssl_connect still under tcp_connect, the return value is still -1 but the SSL_get_error value became 5 which means (SSL_ERROR_SYSCAL) then when we look for errno its value is 104
   . The return value of tcp_connect is 30.

Note:
The end points (webservice addr) that we used is working when we try using windows platform (.net framework). The above issue only encounter in arm-linux devices.

Thanks and best regards,
JC

Comment: Looks like this is caused somewhere deeper in the OpensSL library during the handshake, for example when the connection is prematurely closed by the server or when the network was dropped. Perhaps a SIGPIPE was triggered by the socket library as a result of that.